# Is Short File Name us available in both Windows 64 and Windows32

Tags: windows, win32com, win32-process

According to the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989.aspx), GetShortPathName is in `KERNEL32.DLL`

I have checked the MSDN documentation, however it is not clear to me whether this call is available in both Windows 64 and 32 bit version.

I can see:

```
FileAPI.h (include Windows.h);

WinBase.h on Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, 
Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP (include Windows.h)
```

However the bit version is not mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's present regardless of bitness.

Comment: Can you please provide me a reference link? And thanks.

Comment: Every part of the 32-bit Windows API is present on 64-bit Windows. With perhaps a few exceptions where structures include pointers and thus need to be different. But those places are explicitly spelled out in the documentation. If it weren't that way, there'd be no way you could run 32-bit programs in 64-bit Windows. And also couldn't just keep well-written source compiling for both.